# Cannot connect to hidden WIFI

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, gnome, networkmanager

I noticed an issue: I cannot connect to an hidden WIFI

I activated the *Hotspot* feature on my phone (Android 11, MIUI 12), set up with a WPA2 Personal password, then I also thought to made it *safer* by hiding its SSID.

Unfortunately when my laptop tries to connect, it gives me an error:

```
gnome-control-c[12898]: Failed to activate connection: (2) Connection 'ggggGGGG' is not available on device wlp2s0 because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)
```

But, as soon as I switch off the *hidden SSID* option, everything works!

Can anyone help me fixing this annoying issue?

---

I am on Arch Linux w/ GNOME 41.1

Comment: "_I also thought to made it safer by hiding its SSID_" this adds no "safety" but makes it considerably _more_ visible as devices have to shout for it by name everywhere they go, in case it's there

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a hidden SSID through `wpa_supplicant`.

Stop the NetworkManager service:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

With the following content:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
    ssid="hiden_SSID"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="secret_here"
}
```

Then:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlp2s0 -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo dhcpcd
```

`WPA_SUPPLICANT.CONF(5)`:

```
scan_ssid
         SSID scan technique; 0 (default) or 1.  Technique 0 scans for the
         SSID using a broadcast Probe Request frame while 1 uses a
         directed Probe Request frame
```